# Spring Authorization Server tries to Authenticate OAuth2 Clients against LDAP

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-ldap

I am working on creating an Authorization server, but I have run into an issue where the authorization server is trying to authentication my client, using the password grant_type, against LDAP.

However, what I want is for my client to be authenticated using the ClientDetailsService and then the user specified in the request to be authenticated against LDAP. I am not sure why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am not entirely sure what the cause for the issue is except that the @Order(Order.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) is causing this filter to try and authenticate all request fist, so the request to the token endpoint is not being validated against the right configuration class.

When I hit the OAuth/token endpoint with valid oauth2-client credentials, i get an unauthorized response. However, when I change the client credentials to my ldap credentials, I get invalid client credentials response.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class WebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${example.ldap.url}")
    private String ldapUrl;

    @Value("${example.ldap.base}")
    private String ldapBase;

    @Value("${example.ldap.username}")
    private String ldapUsername;

    @Value("${example.ldap.password}")
    private String ldapPassword;

    @Value("${example.ldap.userDnPattern}")
    private String[] userDnPattern;

    /**
     * This exposes the web-security AuthenticationManager for use in the
     * OauthConfig. This allows us to do LDAP Authentication against the user being
     * supplied by the client.
     */
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
        return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2ClientResourceAssembler oAuth2ClientResourceAssembler() {
        return new OAuth2ClientResourceAssembler();
    }

    @Bean
    BaseLdapPathContextSource contextSource() {
        LdapContextSource ldapContextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        ldapContextSource.setUrl(ldapUrl);
        ldapContextSource.setBase(ldapBase);
        ldapContextSource.setUserDn(ldapUsername);
        ldapContextSource.setPassword(ldapPassword);

        return ldapContextSource;
    }

    /**
     * Allow spring to inject dependencies
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthoritiesPopulator daoAuthoritiesPopulator() {
        return new DaoAuthoritiesPopulator();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.ldapAuthentication().userDetailsContextMapper(new LdapEntryMapper())
                .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(daoAuthoritiesPopulator()).userSearchFilter("(samAccountName={0})")
                .contextSource(contextSource());
    }

    /**
     * Allow only users with ADMIN rights to access the client and user endpoint
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/client/**").hasRole("ADMIN").and().httpBasic();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("ADMIN").and().httpBasic();
        http.authorizeRequests().and().csrf().disable();
    }
}

@Configuration
public class OauthConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2ClientDetailsService oAuth2ClientDetailsService;

    /**
     * Ldap Authentication for password grant types
     */
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.withClientDetails(oAuth2ClientDetailsService);
    }

    /**
     * Inserting an autenticationManager allows for password grant types.
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager).userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
}

@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to change the websecurityconfigurer class to use a regex matcher to only match request that I wanted to apply ldap authentication against. Therefore, all other request fell through to the other configuration classes

```
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.requestMatchers().regexMatchers("/client.+", "/user.+");

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/client/**").hasRole("ADMIN").and().httpBasic();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("ADMIN").and().httpBasic();
        http.authorizeRequests().and().csrf().disable();
    }
```

The developer's guide explain this: [Developer's Guide](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html) in the section titled "Configuring the Endpoint URLs"